# Is there a way to deal with answers that were modified to match yours?

Tags: support, answers

Well I had this strange situation were saw a fairly basic CSS question looked at it and answered in a way where the OP had all the info, but could not copy-paste the answer i.e. would force the OP to think a bit.

Now the solution was a one liner fix, and there was one completely wrong answer there, with basically tried to give a copy-paste answer, but got it wrong.

Not long after I've posted my answer the person who was the first respondent edited their answer to match mine. (With a slight variation, but still.)

Anyway, my current issue with this is, that I really do not like the fact that my answer will linger in the system as a duplicate.

I would simply love to remove the answer, but I can't (would have a negative effect on my rep) and I can expect down votes or mod removal on my answer for being a duplicate... so yeah... cut it as you like I'm on the bad side of things in this case, while having done nothing wrong?

I really do not care about the rep, but I do not want this answer to negatively effect it as well. I would simply be over the moon, if I could simply remove the answer and be done with it, with no negative effect on my rep.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, don't sweat it, move on.